# Optimize Memory iOS App: UIWebView, Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, webview, viewcontroller

I've an iOS app with 3 views in a TabBarViewController:

The first is for parsing JSON data from a website, and display 1-3 pictures with a textarea. The second is a contact view; google maps SDK with another text area. The third view is a webView, used to stream video from a webcam (imported by HTML file).

The first view takes me 35.5MB to display (with one picture).
After I switch on the second view with TabBarViewController, I am using 75MB of memory (if I come back on the first view, it's about 72Mb).
Finally, if I go to the third view (the webView), memory allocation is at about 90MB, unless I'm watching the streaming video from the webcam, when the the memory rises to around 170MB.

I don't know if this is acceptable or not.

I'm using ARC, but I don't use dealloc in my classes. Can I use dealloc when I am using a TabBarViewController? I would like, for example, to dealloc all of the views when I'm changing views with the TabBarViewController, since my memory allocation never decreases.

webView code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.fileUrl = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]URLForResource:@"myHTML" withExtension:@"html"];
    self.requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.fileUrl];
    [_webView loadRequest:self.requestURL];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
    _webView = nil;
    self.fileUrl = nil;
    self.requestURL = nil;
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use WKWebView instead of Webview is really good for memory !**

Other tips ? Google Maps SDK takes too much memory !

Comment: works great for iOS 8, but tons of us still need to support 7 and can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest clearing out the webcam web view after you shift from it using the -viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: like that : 
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    _webView = nil;
}

?

Comment: This seems to do the trick as well
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];

Comment: Mhhh not really, I'm still at 160Mo after leaving my third view :/
Edited with my web view code ;)